# Date to String in Apex for correct Json

Tags: apex

I have a test with dates that I would like to make dynamic to not have to change them in the future

the correct Json should look like :

```
private static final String FAKE_RESPONSE_JSON = '[{"locactionName":"Bamboo", "startDate": "2021-07-25", "endDate":"2021-07-29"}]';
```

To make it more dynamic and test past date I would like to have something like System.today() - 1 but the json ask for a string.
So I tried to use `String.valueOf(System.today() - 1)`

but I get the errors:
System.JSONException: Unexpected character (':' (code 58)): expected a valid value (number, String, array, object, 'true', 'false' or 'null') at [line:1, column:45]

Any idea how I could do it ?
thx you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the date, try this:

```
Datetime myDT = Datetime.now().addDays(-1);
String myDTString = myDT.format('yyyy-MM-dd');
```

For the whole object, you can use a `Map`.

```
List<Map<String,String>> myArrayMap = new List<Map<String,String>>();
Map<String,String> myMap = new Map<String,String>();
myMap.put('locationName','Bamboo');
myMap.put('startDate', myDTString);
myMap.put('startDate', myDTString);
myArrayMap.add(myMap);

String FAKE_RESPONSE_JSON = JSON.serialize(myArrayMap);
```

Comment: Thx you for your answer. I tried 
Datetime myDT = Datetime.now().addDays(-1);
String myDTString = myDT.format('yyyy-MM-dd');
private static final String FAKE_RESPONSE_JSON = '[{"locactionName":"Tel Aviv", "startDate": myDTString, "endDate":"2021-07-29"}]';

But I get System.JSONException: Unexpected character ('m' (code 109)): expected a valid value (number, String, array, object, 'true', 'false' or 'null') at [line:1, column:45]

Comment: As a general rule you should turn a `Datetime` into a `Date` before subtracting days since doing that to a `Datetime` actually subtracts 24 hours, not 1 day (this is different when considering daylight savings transitions). In this case it *may* not matter. Also consider whether you need to provide this from the perspective of a specific time zone. The above will provide yesterday from the perspective of the contextual user, which may not be appropriate.

Comment: I don't think it really matters in this instance.

Comment: @Ben2pop Have you tried my exact code? (which I have verified) Looking at your code, you are embedding the variable in the JSON string - but written like that, it's just a string. You would need to concatenate it, ie `'string1' + var + 'string2'`

Answer (score 0):

It is normally best to hard-code dates in tests and not use e.g. `System.today()`.

Why? As e.g. [You Should Use Static Dates For Your Unit Tests](https://spin.atomicobject.com/2016/12/23/static-dates-unit-tests/) explains:

- Catch Edge Cases Now, Not Later
- Don’t Disrupt Future Development

This might mean hard coding multiple dates, but at least you will have a determinate view of what works.

(The same argument applies if you are tempted to use a e.g. a large set of random numbers in a test case. Generate the random numbers and then hard code them in the test source code.)